# Cannot start Outlook with specific profile using NameSpace.Logon

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop

I try to start Outlook using following code:

```
static Application outlook;
static NameSpace ns;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Outlook already running: {Process.GetProcessesByName("Outlook").Any()}");
    Console.Write("Enter Profile: ");
    var profile = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

    Console.WriteLine($"Using Profile: '{profile}' ...");

    outlook = new Application();
    ns = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
    ns.Logon(profile, "", false, true);

    ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox).Display();
}
```

Output is

```
Outlook already running: False
Enter Profile: Koch
Using Profile: 'Koch' ...
```

There *is* a profile called "Koch". But using this code, Outlook always opens the default profile (Called "Outlook") no matter which profile is entered.

When starting Outlook "manually", it asks for the profile and then starts with the selected profile.

When starting Outlook using `Process.Start` everything works as expected.

```
Process.Start("Outlook", $"/profile \"{profile}\"");
```

How can I assure that `NameSpace.Logon` works as expected?

**EDIT**
I noticed that using `RDOSession.Logon` from Redemption works:

```
RDOSession session = new RDOSession();
session.Logon(profile, Type.Missing, false, false);
```

The correct profile is selected when using this code. But as I would like to start Outlook using Outlook Interop this is not the "solution".

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN docs state the following:

> When users start Outlook a second time, that instance of Outlook runs within the same Outlook process, does not create a new process, and uses the same profile.
>
> If Outlook is already running, using this method does not create a new Outlook session or change the current profile to a different one.

It seems you are running your application under another security context. Take a look at the list of running processes in the Task Manager and make sure no Outlook processes are still running.

Also, you may try to use the UI option for choosing the profile passing `true` to display the MAPI logon dialog box to allow the user to select a MAPI profile. Thus, you can be sure the `Logon` method works correctly.

Comment: There is no other instance of Outlook running in Task Manager. Using `ns.Logon(profile, "", true, true);` does not display the profile dialog ...